# Setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT on Adminer

Tags: oracle, adminer

I am using Adminer 4.7.3 connecting to an oracle DB and I want to display dates in a different format from what the default is ('DD-MON-YY'). I tried using the command
`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'` but it only lasts for that query, and it goes back to the old date format once I open the table again. Is there a better way to force the date to show up in a different format?

Comment: I think you can set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in environment variable. Then it should be default to that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options. First, you can perform an

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'
```

every time you log on. If you don't want to do this you can:

1. If you're using *nix:

   `setenv NLS_DATE_FORMAT "dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss"`
2. If you're using Windows:

   Control Panel-System-Advanced System Settings-Environment Variables, and create the NLS_DATE_FORMAT environment variable with the appropriate setting.
3. If you want an entirely database-dependent solution, you can use an `ON LOGON` trigger similar to the following:

   `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DATABASE_AFTER_LOGON
     AFTER LOGON
     ON DATABASE
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS''';
   END DATABASE_AFTER_LOGON;`

Comment: I tried doing the first thing, but it doesn't "last"; with Adminer, I can enter the command and then enter another query, like 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS; SELECT * FROM dates_table' and it will work, but then if I enter another query, it will show the dates in the default format.

Comment: Sometimes setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT is not sufficient. It is nesessary to set NLS_LANG variable also.